# How to set Sesame 2.8.0 RepositoryConnection timeout

Tags: java, sesame, owlim, graphdb

I am trying to implement something like circuit breaker for my Sesame connections to the back-end database. When the database is absent I want to know this after 2 seconds, not to rely on the defaults of the client for timeouts. I can possibly overcome this with my own FutureTasks where I will execute the repository initialization and the connection obtaining. However in the logs I can see that sesame client uses **o.a.h.i.c.PoolingClientConnectionManager** - which is passed I bet **ExecutorService** and some default timeouts. This will make my **FutureTask** solution pretty messy. Is there an easier way to set timeouts for the  sesame client.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the query and update timeout, specifically, on the query/update object itself:

```
 RepositoryConnection conn = ....;

 ... 
 TupleQuery query = conn.prepareTupleQuery(QueryLangage.SPARQL, "SELECT ...");
 query.setMaxExecutionTime(2);
```

However, if you want to set a general timeout for all api calls over HTTP, the only way to currently do that is by obtaining a reference to the HttpClient object, and reconfigure it:

```
  HTTPRepository repo = ....;
  AbstractHttpClient httpClient = (AbstractHttpClient)((SesameClientImpl)repo.getSesameClient()).getHtttpClient();
  HttpParams params = httpClient.getParams();
  params.setIntParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.SO_TIMEOUT, 2000);
  httpClient.setParams(params);
```

As you can see, this is rather brittle (lots of explicit casts), and uses an approach that is deprecated in Apache HttpClient 4.4. So I don't exactly recommend this as a stable solution, but it should provide a workaround in the short term.

In the longer term the Sesame dev team are working on more convenient access to the configuration of the httpclient.

Comment: Yes. Works. What I added was : **params.setIntParameter(CoreConnectionPNames.CONNECTION_TIMEOUT, 2000);** . Of course setting httpclient's timeouts should be before **repo.initialize()** and **repo.getConnection()**. Thanks a lot!